# Email notification in Assignment rules are not triggered in lightning page controller

Tags: lightning, assignment-rules

I have a lightning page where we are creating a new case,for assignment rules we are using the AssignmentRuleHeader and EmailHeader to assign cases to a Queue and a shoot an email.However my case is being assigned to the queue,but no email is shoot.Here is the code of the controller :

```
@AuraEnabled
public Static String setCaseObject(String objCase,Boolean isCaseAssignment){
    Case caseObj = (Case)JSON.deserialize(objCase, Case.class);
    AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
    AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];

    //Creating the DMLOptions for "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox
    Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
   dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;
      dmlOpts.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail= true;

    //dmlOpts.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;

    caseObj.setOptions(dmlOpts);
    system.debug('objCase'+ caseObj);
    //List<Contact> lstContact = [SELECT ID,Name FROM Contact where (AccountId = :caseObj.AccountId AND SA_Primary_Contact__c = True) ORDER BY createdDate DESC];
    try{
        upsert caseObj;
        return 'Success '+(String)caseObj.Id;
    }
    catch(exception e){
        return String.valueOf(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: check that if queue email id is valid

Comment: Yeah ..it is working if I don't override the new button with my lightning page

Comment: No ...Sry for my last comment ..I want it in lightning page ..which is not throwing email to the queue after assignment ..which I am not able to achieve ..is there anything else you have to do in lightning?